# Smarty error after upgrading civicrm from 5.69.4 to 5.70.0

Tags: upgrade, smarty, drupal-7, smarty3

I'm still using smarty 2, PHP 7.4, drupal 7.99
(note: I have a test site for php 8 and smarty 3 and there are problems with both)

After upgrading from civicrm 5.69.4 to 5.70.0 getting the following error on event registration:

> Message was not parsed due to invalid smarty syntax : Smarty error: [in evaluated template line 476]: syntax error: invalid attribute name: '=' (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 1549)

I tried rolling back the code and that doesn't fix it, which would imply a database change, but I don't see any db sql in the incremental files.

FWIW, the registration goes through but the confirmation email is not generated.

Comment: Are you able to review this PR and leave a comment there https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/29428

Answer (score 1):

I was able to restore values in `civicrm_msg_template` from a backup which seems to have allowed me to roll back to 5.69.4.

Will check out [github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/29428](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/29428) for https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/5006 as per [Demerit](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/181/demerit)'s comment.